# Observable returns string by letters (Karma, Angular)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, observable, karma-runner

I try to mock http service in Angular tests (Karma).
I added something like this is providers array:

```js
{
   provide: service,
   useValue: {
      getData: () =>
         new Observable((subscriber) => {
            subscriber.next('item');
      }),
   },
}
```

When I run tests the results are 'i', 't', 'e', 'm'  not 'item'.

Answer (score 0):

you should also show the code where the `getData` method gets consumed.
anyway, try with: `getData: () => of('item')`